# SUM(Decimal column) does not work as intented in .NET client

Tags: clickhouse

Sum(Decimal(9,2)) returns Decimal38 which gives an error in the .NET implementation of their clickhouse client.

Full issue here:
https://github.com/killwort/ClickHouse-Net/issues/65

Any known work arounds for this?  I expect that SUM(decimal(9,2)) also is a decimal(9,2) col.

Comment: Why not apply casting like this: *toDecimal32(sum(Money), 2)*?

Comment: It works vladimir.... I just don't like to convert columns due to the overhead :D. But Thanks, i can continue!